# Weka Apriori Algorithm Fast Vector Outputs memory location values

Tags: java, vector, machine-learning, weka, apriori

I use `weka` dependency to get the association rules via `Apriori Algorithm`. Below is my code. When I get values `fast vector` displays memory location values. I would be very thankful If someone could post me an answer to get the `association rules` as it is.

```
package com.smart.product.analyser;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import weka.associations.Apriori;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class App {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
        BufferedReader inputReader = null;

        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
        return inputReader;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Define ArrayList to Add Clustered Information
        Apriori apriori = new Apriori();
        apriori.setNumRules(10);
        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("/media/dulithdecozta/IR1_CPRA_X6/FYP-Documents/Transactions.arff");
        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        apriori.buildAssociations(data);
        log.debug("-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-");
        log.debug("Number of Associations : " + apriori.getNumRules());
        log.debug("Adding Association Information to ArrayList ..");
        int num = apriori.getAllTheRules().length;
        System.out.println("Num :" + num);
        for (FastVector fastVector : apriori.getAllTheRules())
            log.debug("rules " + fastVector.toArray());
    }
}
```

Output of the program :

> [Ljava.lang.Object;@7254d7ac
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@201b97d8
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@738df65f

Answer (score 1):

There is none problem with the code

> log.debug("rules " + fastVector.toArray());

it is printing address existing on JVM, in this case, there are three objects that are types from `java.lang.Object`. It is called from `toString()` method existing on `java.lang.Object`

In your case, you must casting this reference to the object `Rules` (i.e., `m_allTheRules`) appropriately. In each case, getting or calling the appropriate method or property.

So, see the example bellow:

```
AprioriItemSet premise = (AprioriItemSet) m_allTheRules[0].elementAt(i);
AprioriItemSet consequence = (AprioriItemSet) m_allTheRules[1].elementAt(i);
```

This is only the example, the `m_allTheRules` is the anonymous variable created inside `foreach` that you provider.

See the full example extracted from [here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Re-How-to-extract-item-elements-from-apriori-td29536.html)